# MySQL inner join table gives repetaed value from unique table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have **two tables** with a PK---->FK Relationship in InnoDB Engine---->**MySQL&PHP**

The Relationship is **one---->many** between first table which is **'Properties'** and second

table which is **'propertyimages'**.  every row in first table is unique but in second table

every row of first table has got many rows in second table How can i **SELECT unique row from

first table and all info about first table from second table here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.PropertyName, 
                properties.PropertyStatus, 
                propertyimages.PropertyImageID, 
                propertyimages.ImagePath 
FROM properties 
   INNER JOIN propertyimages 
      ON properties.PropertyImageID=propertyimages.PropertyImageID 
     AND propertyimages.PropertyImageID=8;
```

it gives result:

```
PropertyName    PropertyStatus     Propertyid       property Image Path
Appartment      For Lease          8                upload/hydrangeas.jpg
Appartment      For Lease          8                upload/jelsh.jpg
Appartment      For Lease          8                upload/penguins.jpg
Appartment      For Lease          8                upload/tulips.jpg
```

In this result the   **PropertyName** and **PropertyStatus** is Repeated but i want a

unique as its stored in the first tableThe **propertyName** and  **PropertyStatus**

belongs to first table.The **Propertyid**   and  **PropertyImagepath** belings to second table.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the edits, it's considered improper to type in a public forum or Q&A site in all caps.  I strongly suggest using what the editor has done as an example going forward. Good luck! :)

Comment: this is how JOIN works. what you want to exactly achieve ?

Comment: You have several images for each property, of course it gives you all those entries...

Comment: i want to give me the PropertyName and PropertyStatus unique but in above its repeted how can i do that i am using in query in php here is the query: $query=mysql_query("SELECT properties.PropertyName, properties.PropertyStatus, propertyimages.PropertyImageID, propertyimages.ImagePath FROM properties LEFT OUTER JOIN propertyimages ON properties.PropertyImageID=propertyimages.PropertyImageID AND propertyimages.PropertyImageID=$property") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Use `group by` or `distinct`

Comment: when i am executing so on top of every page i am receiving the propertyname and status repeated for all images...........????????????????????

Comment: How `PropertyImageID` indexed on both tables, according to being PK or FK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately a join will create a record for each element found in table 2 with a matching parent element (id 8) in the first table.

you could use a GROUP BY id 8 on the first table field, but you may not get all the results you want since it will take the first image only.

could you restructure your process so that when it comes to the images (and thier display) you could just run a single query to get every image related to property 8

you could always use a nested query (presuming you're looking to display images on a page for a property, etc)

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT Propertyid, PropertyName, PropertyStatus FROM properties WHERE (search criteria)");
if (mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0) {
    while ($q1Row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {

        // Insert property specific data here before you display the images
        echo $q1Row['PropertyName']."<br>\n";
        echo $q1Row['PropertyStatus']."<br>\n";

        $query2 = "SELECT PropertyImageID, ImagePath FROM propertyimages WHERE PropertyImageID='".$q1Row['Propertyid']."'"
            if (mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
                while ($q2Row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {

                    // add code here to do whatever you want with the images
                    echo '<image src="'.$q2Row['ImagePath'].'"><br>\n';

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it would also help to know your DB structure .. i'd imagine you'd want something like this

```
table 1 (properties)
  PropertyID (Primary Key)
  PropertyName
  PropertyStatus

table 2 (propertyImages)
  ImageID (Primary Key)
  PropertyID (many to one reference to PropertyID in table 1)
  ImagePath
```

I may be a bit oblivious to the FK method so if there is a lesson here for me as well, i'd love to hear what input you have.

Comment: i restructed but i got while executing this result :  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PropertyImages\DisplayImages.php on line 15

Comment: that just means my query is wrong resulting in an invalid query .. make sure it matches your database structure and that i didn't mess up the fields you use. i always have to watch out for case sensitive and/or typos since my fingers hate me and type the wrong keys.

Comment: i think the proble is with this part WHERE PropertyImageID = '".$proprtyRow['PropertyImageID']."'";....

Comment: I'll have to take your word for as i can't see your revamped code, or your DB .. but basically you take the property ID from query1 and use it as the search criteria on query2 to get your images

Answer (score 0):

you are one step away from the solution, you just need to select from second table and then for first so you will have all you result matched

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.PropertyName, 
            properties.PropertyStatus, 
            propertyimages.PropertyImageID, 
            propertyimages.ImagePath 
FROM propertyimages 
   INNER JOIN properties  
     ON propertyimages.PropertyImageID = properties.PropertyImageID
     AND propertyimages.PropertyImageID=8;
```

Comment: @user2279037 sorry but i'm not sure what you want to retrieve from the query

Comment: @user2279037 can you please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). But I also think, it is better to make two queries. Nothing wrong with that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.PropertyName, 
                properties.PropertyStatus, 
                propertyimages.PropertyImageID, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(propertyimages.ImagePath) 
FROM properties 
   INNER JOIN propertyimages 
      ON properties.PropertyImageID=propertyimages.PropertyImageID 
      AND propertyimages.PropertyImageID=8;
GROUP BY propertyimages.PropertyImageID
```